# Python: ContextualVersionConflict: pandas 0.22.0; Requirement.parse('pandas<0.22,>=0.19'), {'scikit-survival'})

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have this issue:

> ContextualVersionConflict: (pandas 0.22.0 (...),
>   Requirement.parse('pandas<0.22,>=0.19'), {'scikit-survival'})

I have even tried to uninstall pandas and install scikit-survival + dependencies via anaconda. But it still does not work....

Anyone with a suggestion on how to fix?
Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Restarting jupyter notebook fixed it. But I am unsure why this would fix it?